# How cart and checkout internally works in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Can anyone explain how cart and checkout work internally?

means when you click on ADD to cart button what exactly will happen?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to explain everything here, better you ask with the specific problem. Refer [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

---

Now coming to your question

> When you click on ADD to cart button what exactly will happen?

An add to cart form is submitted through ajax call(`.ajaxForm`), you can find the code inside `acc.product.js`. This invokes **addToCart** method of **AddToCartController**, as `/cart/add` request mapped with it. Furthur this controller invoke facads to add selected product to cart and return `AddToCartPopup.jsp` as JSON response, which help to render AddToCartPopup on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can start firstly to read pages which are on helphybris.

Small Explanation :

Cart & Checkout (formerly called Order Management Module) is a set of services that enable you to define your own business process steps such as: authorize payment, capture payment, and cancellation.

Cart & Checkout is a template business process definition for you to extend and integrate with Order Management Services or 3rd party Order Management Systems.

- If you have a access 
  : https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8c20e24d86691014ba61d588779202ae.html
- Another way is making debug. You can put a break point to AddToCartController for debugging to press "add to bag" button on frontend .